# How can I handle multiple activities in a Javascript single-page app?

Tags: javascript, singlepage, single-page-application

For example, I might have a menu screen, an options screen, an editor screen, etc. Previously, I've wrapped each of these into a class an provided and activate and deactivate function for each one. The activate function would show the related dom element and start accepting input. The deactivate function would hide the related dom element and stop accepting input. So if the user was in the menu screen, and clicked on the "set options" button, I would do something like this:

```
this.deactivate() // We're currently in the menu, so the menu object is "this"
options.activate()
```

Is there a standard way of handling this scenario?

Comment: Have you looked at modern single-page frameworks, like Backbone or Ember?

Comment: It depends on how complex you want to get. You could make an event driven site using something such as [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/). You can also create multiple "pages" which run on a single page using ajax requests, DOM manipulation, and a hash controller like [sammyjs](http://sammyjs.org/)

Comment: Too broad a question, not a good fit for SO. It would be a good fit if you showed what you tried and what's not working

Comment: @Juan: Clearly I am missing something since two people have brought it up (and one has been upvoted) -- I thought I had put what I tried inside my question (the code snippet and preceding explanation). Obviously I have a misconception here, but for the life of me I can't fathom what it is. I don't suppose you'd mind enlightening me?

Comment: @shino You showed a concept in your snippet, not anything that could actually be run. You wanted us to explain how to implement a concept. SO is more for "I expected this code to do A but it's doing B". It doesn't mean it's not a good question, but it should be at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @Juan Thanks for responding. I can accept that the question is not a good fit for SO, I'm just not comprehending the "What have you tried?" comments. Are you suggesting that I did not show enough code to demonstrate what I tried? I genuinely do not know what else I could show to make my point more clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are many frameworks that implement what is largely called the "[publish/subscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh201955.aspx)" pattern in JavaScript; Backbone.Events is one that I use frequently.  Here's a really simple way to implement it.  This assumes that you're including both [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org) and [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) in your project.

```
var Foo = {},
    Bar = {};

_.extend(Foo, Backbone.Events);
_.extend(Bar, Backbone.Events);

Foo.prototype.deactivate = function() {
    // Do stuff 
    this.trigger("Foo_Deactivated");
};

Bar.prototype.activate = function() {
    // Do stuff 
    this.trigger("Bar_Activated");
};

myFoo = new Foo();
myBar = new Bar();

myBar.on("Foo_Deactivate", function() { 
    this.activate(); 
    this.trigger("Bar_Activated"); 
}, this);
```

Hope that answers your question!